# get-webbinding -like IIS:\Sites\$variable

Tags: powershell

I have a script that does a get-webbinding and it works fine.  However, I need to do something like the following:

```
$Binding = Get-WebBinding -like $variable
```

So for example,     $variable would be website, but the IIS website would be called website.com.  I need it to do a like comparison, but cannot figure out how to do that.  I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Get websites, iterate, use `-like` operator, and then do the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$SiteName = 'SiteName'
(Get-WebBinding | 
Where bindingInformation -like "*$SiteName*").bindingInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I am new to PS and was having a brain block.  This works perfectly.